# Advanced search tweaking in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magento advance search for searching the products and if i add attribute and enable **"Use in Advanced Search"** means it is showing that field in advance search form and it is searching the field correctly.

For ex: if the attribute is having no.of persons **6** means it is showing the product if we search **6**.

But what i need is make it to show the products which is having more than **6** persons. I want to do some tweaking. Can anyone explain me where i have to do twaekings??... i have looked in to advancedcontroller.php... but i could not get an idea

Answer (score 0):

### Abstraction

The Advanced Search feature goes through a couple of layers of abstraction to get to the actual code that does the searching.

### Indirection

Also the search engine is searching an indexed version of the information (structured for easier search). Because of this you will most likely have override one of the Indexer classes which analyzes the original Product data and generated the indexed version.

### Low level implementation

There's a caveat to doing this -- the Indexer classes need to run fast because they are processing large quantities of data so they are not implemented using the Magento `catalog/product` model for reading product data, they use a lower level (less memory consuming) version.